# http: no cipher suite supported by both client and server

Tags: traefik

#### What did you do?

We are hosting traefik in a docker swarm containing 3 managers. Things are working fine but after a week or so we start getting either of these errors continuously:

 `http: TLS handshake error from 10.255.0.2:56437: tls: no cipher suite supported by both client and server
2017/07/28 06:18:17 server.go:2753: http: TLS handshake error from 10.255.0.2:44674: tls: unsupported SSLv2 handshake received
2017/07/28 06:18:26 server.go:2753: http: TLS handshake error from 10.255.0.2:48083: tls: client using inappropriate protocol fallback
2017/07/28 06:11:12 server.go:2753: http: TLS handshake error from 10.255.0.2:54382: tls: client offered an unsupported, maximum protocol version of 300`

#### What did you expect to see?

Once I hit the service endpoint, I should see our application JSON response.

#### What did you see instead?

Once this error starts showing, our service front end starting giving 502 bad gateway. But not always, 3 in 10 times 502 bad gateway occurs.

#### Output of `traefik version`: (*What version of Traefik are you using?*)

`Traefik Version:
Version:      v1.3.4
Codename:     raclette
Go version:   go1.8.3
Built:        2017-07-27_03:52:53PM
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64`

#### What is your environment & configuration (arguments, toml, provider, platform, ...)?

```
Docker version:
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:20:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:21:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

traefik.toml:

```
  toml

# traefik.toml
accessLogsFile = "log/access.log"
traefikLogsFile = "log/traefik.log"
logLevel = "INFO"

defaultEntryPoints = ["https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      CertFile = "/etc/traefik/traefik.cert"
      KeyFile = "/etc/traefik/traefik.key"

[web]
address = ":8080"
ReadOnly = true

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "docker.localhost"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = true
swarmmode = true
```

I can see 10.255.0.2 as ingress-endpoint from ingress. Copying the detail of ingress:
The Strange thing is, it was working. Without any change suddenly fails followed by this error.

docker network inspect ingress.

```
json
[
{
    "Name": "ingress",
    "Id": "g91vlveu6s2u9c4tvzqdn2e8y",
    "Created": "2017-07-27T10:01:09.111025266Z",
    "Scope": "swarm",
    "Driver": "overlay",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "10.255.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "10.255.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": true,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "bfdee6bece2b0750796d39533793286f599ad3f38855f4518ac545cf02048473": {
            "Name": "traefik.qml805v1p6e35ewm3e6f1qko8.zbyxdt4vawobelqp8pz7lxdp5",
            "EndpointID": "6e0e5f3d4c6bede800d6948aaa6da6f6b4df0e51d4e9b43c3fc9be88385e966e",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:ff:00:07",
            "IPv4Address": "10.255.0.7/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "ingress-sbox": {
            "Name": "ingress-endpoint",
            "EndpointID": "10adf1878e093da50c7bfe7dcda2c0c1cdb5271db9b31c49553e4a031b20244b",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:ff:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "10.255.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4096"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
```

]

Most of the time we see this issue occurring when the machines are restarted.